# Graph $T_n$ are completely positive

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

The graph $T_n$ on n vertices, consisiting of n-2 triangles with common base, is completely positive.

Let $A$ be a matrix realization of $T_n$. We may assume that $A$ is nonsingular and that its diagonal entries are all equal to $1$. If the common base $T_n$ is $\{1,2\}$, then $A$ is of form

$$A= \begin{pmatrix} B &C \\ C^T & I_{n-2}\end{pmatrix}$$

where $B \in Mat_{2 \times 2}$ nonegative matrix, and $C \in  Mat_{\{2 \times (n-2)\}}$ is a positive matrix.

So $$A= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{A}{I_{n-2}} &0 \\ 0& 0_{n-2} \end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix} C\\ I_{n-2} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} C^T  I_{n-2}\end{pmatrix}$$ 
Then we end the proof with Schur complement and Theorem about sum of certain matrix. 
Is there any easier way to prove that?